# Craft 2 - Feed Me unique cUrl Options with Multiple feeds

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm using the FeedMe plugin for Craft 2 and I would like to run multiple feeds each with different cUrl options  but there is no documentation on how to do that with the Craft 2 plugin.

Craft 3 Docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/get-started/configuration.html

```
feedOptions' => [
            '1' => [
                'feedUrl' => 'https://specialurl.io/feed.json',
                'requestOptions' => [],
            ]
        ],
```

Craft 2 Docs: https://github.com/engram-design/feed-me/blob/craft-2-docs/docs/get-started/configuration.md

```
<?php

return array(
    '*' => array(
        'curlOptions' => array(
            // Example
            // CURLOPT_PROXY => 'username:password',
        ),
        'checkExistingFieldData' => false,
        'skipUpdateFieldHandle' => 'skipFeedMeUpdate',
        'backupLimit' => 100,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For FeedMe under Craft 2, you are likely going to need to extend the base feed types to create your own feed type that has custom logic, such as authentication. Sadly, the data types documentation under Craft 2 was always TBC, however this plugin can demonstrate how you can create your own feed types

https://github.com/surprisehighway/craft-feedmehelper

You essentially need to hook into the registerFeedMeDataTypes() function to register a feed type which is then selectable as a feed in the FeedMe feeds menu.